# Pointer arithmetic and dynamic memory?

Tags: c

What does the following piece of code mean?

```
int* pointer = malloc (sizeof(int) + 3);
pointer++;
```

The allocated piece of memory can't be broken down into chunks of  `sizeof(int)`. So what happens when pointer is asked to jump to the next "block"? Is it defined?

Comment: @TimCooper Yeah, but what is the pointer set to now?

Comment: @BrainSteel I don't understand. Could you please add in details?

Comment: This may be undefined behavior on a machine with 4-byte ints... Because you don't own ALL of the memory. Sorry about the previous comment. I didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: It's not "defined".  In practice the malloced space will almost certainly be "rounded up" to a multiple of 8 or 16, so an access to the incremented pointer will not "cross" heap allocations, but technically you can't depend on that.  (But, generally speaking, you can increment pointers til the cows come home, so long as you don't dereference them.  Probably not technically "defined" but "safe" in pretty much all environments.)

Comment: @BrainSteel is right - but on platforms where `int` is four bytes long you will have trouble when accessing this memory, since `malloc` will only have set aside seven bytes for you. But often it does some boundary alignment so you might get away with it. Just incrementing the pointer is perfectly valid. Accessing the memory it points to (which your code snippet doesn't do) is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is valid but maybe unusual without more context.

Line 1: The `malloc` allocates 3 bytes larger than the size of an `int`.  This is valid.

Line 2: The `pointer++` is valid.  It's just an address.

Further references to `pointer` (e.g. addition or subtraction or comparison) are valid.  Dereferences (i.e. `*pointer`) will result in undefined behaviour.

Not that those 3 "extra" bytes are valid storage space and can be addressed with a `char *`, for example.

Comment: @dfg, no.  Since you've declared `pointer` as type `int*`, the `++` operation will always increment `pointer` by `sizeof int`.  This may be 4 bytes.  Possibly 8.  It will not be 3.

If, for example, you wanted a pointer to the first of those 3 extra bytes, you could do this: `char *c = (char *)pointer + (sizeof int);` and then `c` is a pointer that will increment one byte at a time.

I hope this helps. If my answer above was useful, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, let me know what is unclear.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`pointer` can be used for pointer comparison (C standard allows pointers to be one element past the last one).  Read or write access is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

`*pointer` is 3 bytes of 0 and `sizeof(int) - 3` bytes of undefined.  Which byte[s] (as related to significance in your `int`) are undefined is platform dependent (on the system bytesex) so in terms of your C program, the whole thing might as well be undefined.